# Stackview swift iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, uistackview, portrait

Trying to use stackviews in my new app. This is how I want the app to look like. All UIViews are squares and scale with ratio 1:1. Labels should be placed just outside uiviews. Labeltext should also scale.

[image]

Tried to put the elements in stacks like this, but it is behaving weird.
[image]

How can I make the inner square (with the uiviews) as big as possible and make the labels float around the square?

Comment: Behaving weird how? Please add what you have tried and what the results of that have been, and exactly what you don't understand about what's happening.

Comment: I would like the square to have a total width approximately 80% of screen width and the labels 10% each. Is it possible to control stack views like that?

Comment: Yes there are multiple ways to get this done -- have you tried using a `UIStackViewDistribution` of `.fillProportionally`? If the content sizes of the three elements are relatively 10%, 80%, and 10%, then they will fill the horizontal space in that proportion.

Comment: I think my main problem is that I don't really understand the stackview logic.

Comment: I think my main problem is that I don't really understand the stackview logic. The first three labels and the button are not so difficult. Regarding the uiview-square and the labels around it I have the following algorithm - First put three and three uiviews in a stackview, then the three stackviews in to another one. All the uiviews are now in one square. Each uiView should be the same height and width and I would like them to scale up and down dependant on screen size. Should I now put the middle left label, the stack of stackviews and the middle right label in a new stackview?

Answer (score 0):

I have attached the solution with UIView to be squares with aspect ration 1:1 and minimum/maximum value for labels

You can change the spacing of stackview containing labels programmatically to match the edges with square view of UIViews

Please check out the constraints of UIViews, relationships with other views (like equal widths/heights etc) distribution and spacing of stackviews

This checked this on iPhone 8/SE and iPad Pro and it viewed fine in Preview of storyboard except of the spacing of UILabels which can be set programmatically

The solution is uploaded to github [here](https://github.com/nanduahmed/uistackview)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your solution is great for iPhone 8 plus, but labels do not follow uiview-square in other sizes.

Comment: @Apprentice , change the spacing in stackview programmatically for other iPhones